# Using JavaScript to increment top/left/bottom/right values

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to increment the position of an element by, say, *x* pixels. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
var top = document.getElementById("something").style.top;
top = top + "300px"
```

I know that this is not going to work, but I was wondering if it was possible to increment a position value like this.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  This is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because `style.top` is a string with units on the end of it like `"300px"` you can only do math with it when you convert just the numeric part to an actual number.

Assuming you have a positioned element (so setting the `top` value will do something) and you already have a `top` style set directly on the element and not set via CSS (so getting `obj.style.top` will actually get you something), you can do it by parsing the number out of the style value like this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("something");
var topVal = parseInt(obj.style.top, 10);
obj.style.top = (topVal + 300) + "px";
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pt46X/

Comment: I have typed up a small code : http://jsfiddle.net/wLf35/ I can't seem to find the error here though.

Comment: @day0 - As I said in my answer, `obj.style.top` will not retrieve a value set in CSS.  You will need to use a cross-browser version of `window.getComputedStyle()` if your style is set via CSS.  `obj.style.top` only retrieves style values set directly on the object (not via CSS).  In the jsFiddle, you also have to set the code to be head or body so that your functions are in the global scope and will be reachable the way you are calling them.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CG68f/

Comment: Ah that's great! Thank you very much. I hadn't come across `.getComputedStyle()` anywhere. Thanks again!

Comment: @day0 -  Just keep in mind that IE before IE9 does not support `getComputedStyle()`.  You have to use the `currentStyle` property instead.  A google search will show you lots of cross browser ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

That won't work fine because, for example, if `top` had a value of `200px`, it would become `"200px300px"`. Try this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("something");
elem.style.top = parseInt(elem.style.top, 10) + 300 + "px"
```

[Demo WEEEE!!!!](http://jsfiddle.net/u7uzf/)

Answer (score 0):

```
let top = 0;
let left = 0;
let text = document.getElementById("TextToTranslate");
text.setAttribute("style","top:"+top+"px; "+left+":px;");
```

use this in a while loop and it works fine, i'm just figuring out how to slow it down so i can see the transition