# JavaScript top and left positions not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code in JavaScript on a HTML file but when I run it the image that I have doesn't move when I change top or left. Why is this happening, I have been searching for hours and copying tones of code to see if it works but nothing. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?
Here is the code:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Website</title>
<h1 id="txt_1">Value: 0</h1>
<h2 id="txt_2">Increments: 0</h2>
<img src="---" id="img_1" style="width:40px;height:40px;top:1000px;left:100px">
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" onclick="down();"><</button>
<button type="button" onclick="up();">></button>
X<input type="text" id="box_x" value=0></input>
Y<input type="text" id="box_y" value=0></input>
</body>

<footer>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
</footer>

<script>
var val = 0;
var add = 0;
function up(){
add++;
updateUI();
}
function down(){
add--;
updateUI();
}
function updateUI(){
document.getElementById("txt_1").innerHTML = "Value: " + val;
document.getElementById("txt_2").innerHTML = "Increments: " + add;

document.getElementById("img_1").style.top = 80 + "px";

}
function update(){
val+=add;
document.getElementById("myCanvas").height = val + 10;
document.getElementById("myCanvas").width = val + 10;
document.getElementById("txt_1").innerHTML = "Value: " + val;
}
setInterval(update,100);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You didn't find a solution for this because this is a CSS problem, not a JavaScript problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JavaScript to increment top/left/bottom/right values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115258/using-javascript-to-increment-top-left-bottom-right-values)

Comment: For starters, your HTML is invalid.

Comment: All elements visible on the UI goes inside the `body` element. This includes the `footer` element.

Comment: It also includes h1, h2 and img.  the head tag should not contain and visible elements.  You can use the header tag instead, inside the body tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any defined styles or link to a .css file. But, your image should have a "position:absolute" in its style somewhere if you want to move it around.

Use this:

```
<img src="---" id="img_1" style=""position:absolute;width:40px;height:40px;top:1000px;left:100px">
```

Instead of this:

```
<img src="---" id="img_1" style="width:40px;height:40px;top:1000px;left:100px">
```

Comment: Where should i add "position:absolute", i'm new to JavaScript so i don't know much.

Comment: For testing, change this line: <img src="---" id="img_1" style="width:40px;height:40px;top:1000px;left:100px"> to <img src="---" id="img_1" style=""position:absolute;width:40px;height:40px;top:1000px;left:100px">

Comment: Also what exactly do you mean by "when I run it the image that I have doesn't move", the function that you have seems to always set top to 80px