# Move image in every click javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I try to move the image in every click but it just move one time.See the code:

```
<img id="myImg" src="">
<script>
function move() {
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg")
    img.style.left += "2px";
}
</script>
<button onclick="move()"></button>
```

Anyone knows how to make it work?

Comment: `console.log(img.style.left, img.style.left + '2px')` and take a look at what is happening

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using JavaScript to increment top/left/bottom/right values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115258/using-javascript-to-increment-top-left-bottom-right-values)

Answer (score 0):

When you get the value of `left` property, it looks like this: `0px`. It's a string. So if you want to calculate it, you need to parse it to a number. Before doing that, you can split `px` part to get the number.

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img id = "myImg" src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474511320723-9a56873867b5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
<script>
function move(){
  var img = document.getElementById("myImg");

  img.style.left = +img.style.left.substring(0, img.style.left.length - 2) + 2 + 'px';
}
</script>
<button onclick = "move()">Move</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
img.style.left += "2px";
```

produces invalid CSS. You want to extract the integer each time, add 2, then add the "px" unit back in.

```js
const img = document.getElementById("myImg")

function move() {
  img.style.marginLeft = img.style.marginLeft ? parseInt(img.style.marginLeft, 10) + 2 + "px" : "2px"
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://placekitten.com/200/200">

<button onclick="move()">Move Image</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very clumsy way to move an image. Please educate yourself about canvas object. But as you are a begginer and may just need a quick fix, here's a way to get your code working:

```html
<img id = "myImg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src ="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/ec/Soccer_ball.svg/600px-Soccer_ball.svg.png">
<script>
var margin = 0;
function move(){
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg")
    margin += 2;
    img.style.marginLeft = margin + "px";
}
</script>
<button onclick = "move()" >Move</button>
```

Comment: NP. If it was helpful to you, please accept/upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*if you want to move image then you could move it either right or left for that try to fix your code at `left - px`*

```
    <img id = "myImg" src = "">
    <script>
    function move(){
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg")
    img.style.left += "2px";
    }
function moveleft() {
               imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
            }

    </script>
    <button onclick = "moveleft();">
```